# How can I split a string, then use the parts to create an object, and then create an array with these objects?

Tags: java, arrays, object, intellij-idea

I need to solve a somewhat complicated task, but I don't seem to get it right.

I have the following String:

```
String text = "John.Davidson/Belgrade Michael.Barton/Krakow Ivan.Perkinson/Moscow";
```

In short, the program flow should be like this:

- split the given String into multiple parts to get first name, last name, and cities;
- use the obtained data to create the Person object;
- put the obtained Person objects into a Person[] array;
- loop through an array and print out its data.

On output, the following display should be obtained for the string given as an example:

- John Davidson Belgrade
- Michael Barton Krakow
- Ivan Perkinson Moscow

This is the main code:

```
public class Program {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String text = "John.Davidson/Belgrade Michael.Barton/Krakow Ivan.Perkinson/Moscow";
        String[] array1 = text.split("[/. ]");
        for (String s : array1) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
        Person[] array = new Person[3];
        for  (int i=0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            array[i] = new Person();
        }
        array[0] = new Person("John", "Davidson","Belgrade");
        array[1] = new Person("Michael", "Barton", "Krakow");
        array[2] = new Person("Ivan", "Perkinson","Moscow");
        for (Person value : array) {
            System.out.println(value);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the Person class:

```
public class Person {
    public String name;
    public String surname;
    public String city;
    public Person(){};
    public Person(String name, String surname, String city){
        this.name = name;
        this.surname = surname;
        this.city = city;
    }
    public String getInfo() {
        return "Name: " + this.name + "\n" + "Surname: " + this.surname + "\n" + "City: " + this.city;
    }
}
```

Unfortuntaley, the result is this:

John

Davidson

Belgrade

Michael

Barton

Krakow

Ivan

Perkinson

Moscow

Person@5f184fc6

Person@3feba861

Person@5b480cf9

What am I doing wrong? I don't know even what the last three entries are...

PS: Sorry for my bad English, not a native speaker.

Comment: Override the `toString` method

Answer (score 2):

Split on space first, the iterate the array of names and do a replacement:

```java
String text = "John.Davidson/Belgrade Michael.Barton/Krakow Ivan.Perkinson/Moscow";
String[] names = text.split(" ");
List<String> output = Arrays.stream(names)
                            .map(x -> x.replaceAll("[./]", " "))
                            .collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(output);

// [John Davidson Belgrade, Michael Barton Krakow, Ivan Perkinson Moscow]
```

Answer (score 1):

What are you trying to do was wrong
you cant initialise the array with a fixed size cause you dont know how much persons are present in the string, so you better use an arrayList

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String text = "John.Davidson/Belgrade Michael.Barton/Krakow Ivan.Perkinson/Moscow";
        String[] personsString = text.split(" ");
        List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<Person>();
        
        for (String ps : personsString) {
            String firtname = ps.split("/")[0].split("\\.")[0];
            String lastname = ps.split("/")[0].split("\\.")[1];
            String city = ps.split("/")[1];
            persons.add(new Person(firtname, lastname, city));          
        }
        
        for (Person person : persons) {
            System.out.println(person.getInfo());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would split on space(s) first, because that operation already separates the values per person.

If you want to combine both of the previous answers to have a list of `Person` objects, you could do it like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // your example input
    String text = "John.Davidson/Belgrade Michael.Barton/Krakow Ivan.Perkinson/Moscow";
    // split by arbitrary amount of whitespaces
    String[] personInfos = text.split("\\s+");
    // stream the result
    List<Person> persons = Arrays.stream(personInfos)
            // and split the Strings to extract the info parts and create Persons from those
            .map(x -> new Person(
                        // split by dot has name as first element
                        x.split("\\.")[0],
                        // splitting the second element of above operation by slash provides surname
                        x.split("\\.")[1].split("/")[0],
                        // and city
                        x.split("\\.")[1].split("/")[1]
                    )
            ).collect(Collectors.toList());
    // print each person's toString()
    persons.forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

**Provided** you override the `Person::toString()` as follows…

```
public class Person {
    …
    
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("%s, %s (%s)", surname, name, city);
    }
}
```

… the output will be this:

```
Davidson, John (Belgrade)
Barton, Michael (Krakow)
Perkinson, Ivan (Moscow)
```